# Find leaf directories contained within directories matching a wildcard

Tags: linux, find, wildcard

The following works very well. It gets me leaf directories.

```
find .  -type d -links 2
```

What I need is something like below. In the current directory, there are directories named as C2S7*, within those I need the leaf directories.

```
find . -name "C2S7*" -type d -links 2
```

The above looks for the wildcard in the leaf directory names as well. What is the alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To look inside direct children matching the pattern:

```
find C2S7*/ -type d -links 2
```

To look inside direct or indirect children matching the pattern:

```
find . -path "*/C2S7*/*" -type d -links 2
```

[Specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html).